# Prove $\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\dfrac{b}{d}$ if $ad=bc$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well obviously if $\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\dfrac{b}{d}$ holds then $cbx+bd=bd+adx$ and it holds for any $x$ if $ad=bc$.

However, my question is to 'algebraically' or 'directly' calculate the $\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ if $ad=bc$. By multiplying both denominator any numerator by any possible guess it doesn't reduce to a constant!

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying 
$$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
by $\frac{bd}{bd}\ (=1)$ gives
$$\frac{b(adx+bd)}{d(bcx+bd)}=\frac{b(bcx+bd)}{d(bcx+bd)}\tag1$$
since $ad=bc$.

Now $(1)$ equals $\frac bd$.

Comment: I think this is the solution OP is looking for.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you :)

Comment: May I add after your first equality, "where we've changed $adx$ to $bcx$ because $ad = bc$" ? I think that makes it a little easier to see where the hypothesis that $ad = bc$ enters into your algebra. Lovely answer, by the way.

Comment: @JohnHughes: Thanks. I've added a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $d(ax+b)=(ad)x+bd=(bc)x+bd=b(cx+d)$. From here, the conclusion is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If $ad=bc$ then $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$.

Let's denote this value by $\beta$. Then we have $a=\beta b\text{ and }c=\alpha d\text.$

So then $$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\frac{\beta bx + b}{\beta dx + d}=\frac{b(\beta x+1)}{d(\beta x+1)} = \frac{b}{d}\text.$$